Why is Crontab telling me I have a premature EOF in my certbot script?
This is my cron file.
SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin

0 3 * * * root certbot certonly --non-interactive --agree-tos --email=${EMAIL} --preferred-challenges=dns --authenticator=dns-duckdns --dns-duckdns-token=${TOKEN} --dns-duckdns-propagation-seconds=180 --quiet -d ${SUBDOMAINS} >> /var/log/letsencrypt/certbot-cron.log 2>&1

I can run the command manually with no problem. And I've ensured that the directory for the log exists. Currently, when I run the full command certbot certonly --non-interactive --agree-tos --email=${EMAIL} --preferred-challenges=dns --authenticator=dns-duckdns --dns-duckdns-token=${TOKEN} --dns-duckdns-propagation-seconds=180 --quiet -d ${SUBDOMAINS} >> /var/log/letsencrypt/certbot-cron.log 2>&1, I get a redir error with no additional context. When I run it without the 2>&1 at the end, then the command runs to completion with no issue. But when I take the whole file and run it with crontab to setup the job, it tells me there was a premature EOF and it failed to install.

First I do not see set of the variables like EMAIL, etc. Set them! Also you use format for common /etc/cron..... files. Did you enter this editing cron with command crontab -e ....?
